# cannot select QAbstractItemView item, when it's disabled

Tags: qt, model-view

When I set flags of QAbstractItemModel selectable but not enabled, I can't select items by mouse click. However internally select() function selects objects.
Is this qt bug, or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood, you want to "Disable" the item, but at the same time, be able to select it. it's fairly easy to fake that on the model.

```
if ( role == Qt::BackgroundRole ){
    return QVariant(QApplication::palette()->color(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Window );
}
```

This will paint your item as grayed out, and you will still be able to select it.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something wrong. If you disable a widget it is greyed out and it doesn't receive user mouse clicks and keyboard input.

Comment: I does not disable a widget. I just set items flags without Qt::ItemIsEnabled flag. The QTreeView widget receives mousePressEvent, but it does not select the item.

Comment: It's clearly stated in the documentation: Qt::ItemIsEnabled The user can interact with the item. So if you set it to NOT enabled, this means that the user CANNOT interact with the item, he CANNOT select or edit it.

Comment: There's also ItemIsSelectable, unsetting that should help against programmatic selection.

Comment: Actually it's wrong. If the item is disabled, double clicking on it still emits "activated" signal

Answer (score 0):

I just had similar problem (I need to copy disabled items). Here is solution that sets correct style for disabled items (without ignoring any style sheets).

Create custom item delegate for your model.

```
/// Returns false only if item needs to be rendered as disabled.
bool isIndexEnabled(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    // Implement this function.
}

class ItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    explicit ItemDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {}

protected:
    void initStyleOption(
        QStyleOptionItemView *option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
        if (!isIndexEnabled(index))
            option->state &= ~QStyle::State_Enabled;
    }
};
```

Set the new item delegate to your model.

```
auto itemDelegate = new ItemDelegate(model)
model->setItemDelegate(itemDelegate);
```